# NodeJS multi-threaded app: Worker load is maxed out, thread uses <50% core time

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I'm porting a game server to Javascript using NodeJS. Computation tasks are run in dedicated threads; This goes for physics simulation as well.

The CPU/Core load makes me wonder about the resource allocated to NodeJS workers. The computer is an i7 (4 cores, no hyperthreading) and a Windows 7 is run.

The code is provided right after listing the highlights of this testbed:

- the main.js code simulates a parent process i.e. the listener thread. It's launching worker threads to handle calculation in non-blocking worker threads.
- the physics.js code simulates a physics calculator, running CPU intensive busywork.
- physics simulation is updated every 16ms
- each update (step) reports its CPU usage to identify starvation
- despite running 2 worker threads per CPU core in the testbed, the total CPU load won't exceed 70-80%.

I would have expected that maxing-out the worker's computation needs (i.e. reported load > 100%) would have required 1 thread per CPU core to reach 100% resource usage.

**What am I doing/understanding wrong?**

Below, the system monitor, showing 8 threads, all outputting >100% usage in NodeJS console yet none is above 10% of CPU processing power as per the sysmon report.

Even with 4 threads, none is above 10% of CPU processing power like there is a limitation to the max total CPU availability a NodeJS thread can consume.

[image: CPU load is < 100% while computing resources seem maxed-out]

main.js:

```
var cp = require('child_process');

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){

    var child = cp.fork('./physics');
    child.processId = i;

    console.log('Process ' + i + ' created');

    child.on('message', function(m) {

        console.log('Process ' + this.processId + ': ' + m);
        //child.kill();
    });
}
```

Observe on line 3 that **i < 4** meaning it's running 4 threads.

Now the physics.js :

```
function simulatePhysics(){

     // var world = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0, 10), true);

     process.send("Physics world creation complete");

    update();
};

// Expected step duration: 16.66ms (60Hz)
var stepDuration = 1000 / 60;

 function update(dt){

    // Clock in
    var dateIn = Date.now();
    {
        // rem: B2D uses seconds, not milliseconds
        // world.Step(dt * 1000, 10, 10);
        // world.ClearForces();

        // Simulate CPU intensive processing
        // rem: takes ~20ms/loop on this 2.9GHz i7-3520M, each step is over time
        var a;
        for(var i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) a++;
    }
    // Clock out
    var dateOut = Date.now();

    // Delta clock
    var delta = dateOut - dateIn;

    process.send("Core load: " + (100 * delta /  stepDuration).toFixed(0) + "%");

    if(delta > stepDuration){

        // Immediately run another step using real step duration
        setTimeout(function(){update(delta)}, 0);
    }

    else{

        // Wait until the 1000/60ms are passed before processing the next step
        var idle = stepDuration - delta;
        setTimeout(function(){update(stepDuration)}, idle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought nodejs was single-threaded. I will stay around to learn some...

Comment: Hi @ikaros45, actually the default use made of NodeJS runs all logic in the listener thread.
The setInterval and setTimout are executed (and blocking, if hefty) within the calling thread.
You can either fork or cluster your server. First case is used in my question, allowing to delegate specific logic to your workers OR you can create a cluster that will load-balance the logic among the workers. Google "node JS cluster" for more, both approaches are native NodeJS.